# Paypal I am not getting login page I have redirected to paypal controller

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I have got console error like this:
Failed to load resource https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/MERCHANTPAYMENTWEB-640-20140614-1/Checkout/js/min/widgets.js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'CSS_HEADER' of undefined checkout.js:164
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'init' of undefined login.js:7
body.scrollTop is deprecated in strict mode. Please use 'documentElement.scrollTop' if in strict mode and 'body.scrollTop' only if in quirks mode.

Any body please help I am not getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to the setting error in the chrome of my computer . some unwanted apps got installed . I need reset my chrome setting .It is blocking secured information over there .
Thank you friends